# ee.Number.toFloat is not a function in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am getting an error trying to parse a number to float in GEE, here is my code:

```
var getUHI = function(feature) {
  var urban = ee.Number(feature.get('LST_urb_day_CT'));
  var UHIday = ee.Number.toFloat(urban.subtract(ee.Number(feature.getNumber('LST_rur_day'))));
  return feature.set({UHIday: UHIday});
};

var UHIAdded = urb.map(getUHI);
```

currently in the featureCollection UHIAdded, 'LST_urb_day_CT' and 'LST_rur_day' are both type float, but after I parse them to numbers to calculate UHIday, UHIday becomes Number. I want to parse UHIday back to float but it tells me toFloat is not a function?

Comment: Does `var UHIday = urban.subtract(ee.Number(feature.getNumber('LST_rur_day'))).float()` work?

Comment: it still says that UHIday is a Number not a float...

Answer (score 1):

You can get float from a number like so:

```
var UHIday = ee.Number(urban.subtract(ee.Number(feature.getNumber('LST_rur_day')))).float()
```

Comment: it still says that UHIday is a Number not a float...

Comment: I believe javascript sees all numbers as only numbers. if there is decimals then it is considered a float, otherwise it's a integer... But it will remain a Number.